# How to detect a client-side initiated "cancel" on the server-side during a doGet in an HttpServlet?

Tags: ios, tomcat, servlets, nsurlconnection, asihttprequest

I have a simple HttpServlet running on Tomcat, which serves a 3.5M long text file.

I'm accessing the servlet from iOS (using ASIHTTPRequest) and I'm doing a "cancel" after 2 seconds (i.e. long before all the data has arrived...)

On the client-side, I can definitely see that the transaction is indeed canceled.

The problem is that I don't have any trivial way to be aware of that on the server-side, and therefore, it looks like the servlet is always sending the full 3.5M.

I would have expected something like an exception, but it's not happening...

The servlet code is as follows:

```
public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException
{
  int read = 0;
  int total = 0;

  try
  {
    response.setContentType("text/html");
    ServletContext ctx = getServletContext();
    InputStream is = ctx.getResourceAsStream("/WarAndPeace.html");

    byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];
    OutputStream os = response.getOutputStream();

    while ((read = is.read(bytes)) != -1)
    {
      os.write(bytes, 0, read);
      total += read;
    }

    os.flush();
    os.close();
    is.close();
  }
  catch (Exception e)
  {
    // NEVER REACHED
  }

  /*
   * THIS PART IS ALWAYS REACHED WITH total = 3.5M BYTES
   * NO MATTER IF THE CONNECTION WAS CANCELED ON THE CLIENT-SIDE
   *
}
```

Any clues? Thanks!

N.B. I also tried with a properly-canceled NSURLConnection (instead of ASIHTTPRequest), but the results are similar.

Comment: It *should* throw an exception on flush. This look too much like that the cause of the problem is in the client side. You could *try* moving `os.flush()` to end of `while` loop, but as you said that the exception is never thrown, I don't think that anything will help solving the problem in server side.